# Make jar file run hidden

Tags: vb.net, jar, apktool

I am making a GUI based Android Application Editor. I used Apktool.jar in my application to decompile and Recompile apks.

But When my application run Apktool.jar it show up as a console window. I want to make apktool.jar hidden.

Is it possible? and how? I am using Visual Studio 2013 and VB language.

Thanks :)

Comment: Please show us how you call apktool.jar in your project.

Comment: very sorry for I cant reply in time. I used "Process.start("apktool.jar") to run it

Answer (score 0):

you should download the source code of apktool
hidden the console screen 
and recompile it